# How to type error in createAsyncThunk with Axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I have a question on handling errors in createAsyncThunk with TypeScript.

I declared returned type and params type with generics. However I tried with  handling erros typing I ended up just using 'any'.

Here's api/todosApi.ts...

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const todosApi = {
    getTodosById
}

// https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/5
function getTodosById(id: number) {
    return instance.get(`/todos/${id}`);
}

// -- Axios
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
})

instance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
        return { status: error.response.status };
    }
    return Promise.reject(error.response);
});

function bearerAuth(token: string) {
    return `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

Here's todosActions.ts

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { todosApi } from '../../api/todosApi'

export const fetchTodosById = createAsyncThunk<
    {
        userId: number;
        id: number;
        title: string;
        completed: boolean;
    },
    { id: number }
>('todos/getTodosbyId', async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {

        const response = await (await todosApi.getTodosById(data.id)).data
        return response
    // typescript infer error type as 'unknown'. 
    } catch (error: any) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data)
    }
})
```

And this is todosSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { fetchTodosById } from './todosActions'

interface todosState {
    todos: {
        userId: number;
        id: number;
        title: string;
        completed: boolean;
    } | null,
    todosLoading: boolean;
    todosError: any | null; // I end up with using any
}

const initialState: todosState = {
    todos: null,
    todosLoading: false,
    todosError: null
}

const todosSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'todos',
    initialState,
    reducers: {

    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchTodosById.pending, (state) => {
                state.todosLoading = true
                state.todosError = null
            })
            .addCase(fetchTodosById.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.todosLoading = false
                state.todos = action.payload
            })
            .addCase(fetchTodosById.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.todosLoading = false
                state.todosError = action.error
            })


    }
})

export default todosSlice.reducer;
```

In addition, it seems my code doesn't catch 4xx errors. Is it becasue I didn't throw an error in getTodosById in todosApi?

I don't have much experience with TypeScript so please bear with my ignorance.

UPDATE: I managed to handle errors not using 'any' type, but I don't know if I'm doing it right.

```
//todosActions..
export const fetchTodosById = createAsyncThunk<
    {
        userId: number;
        id: number;
        title: string;
        completed: boolean;
    },
    number
>('todos/getTodosbyId', async (id, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const response = await todosApi.getTodosById(id);
    if (response.status !== 200) {
        return rejectWithValue(response)
    }
    return response.data
})

// initialState...
todosError: SerializedError | null;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the [Usage with TypeScript](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk) documentation page:

```
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk<
  // Return type of the payload creator
  MyData,
  // First argument to the payload creator
  number,
  {
    // Optional fields for defining thunkApi field types
    rejectValue: YourAxiosErrorType
  }
>('users/fetchById', async (userId, thunkApi) => {
  // ...
})
```